# moving an object in the direction it is facing: java

Tags: java, rotation

so I am attempting to make the base engine for a small test game that is a top down shooter. I have the rotation down for the most part, but I cannot get it to move correctly in the direction it is facing. 
package games;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Rotation extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    private static double i = 0, inc = 0.1, iBase, speed = 0;
    private static int xPos = 0, yPos = 0, width = 100, height = 50;

    static boolean pressedA = false, pressedD = false, slowdown = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(i);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Rotation r = new Rotation();
        f.add(new Rotation());
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addKeyListener(r);


        while(true){
            move();
            accelerate();
            f.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);

        }

    }
public static void move(){
        xPos += speed * Math.cos(-1*Math.PI*i/180);
        yPos -= speed * Math.sin(-1*Math.PI*i/180);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void accelerate(){
        if(i>= 360)
            i=0;
        if(pressedA)
            i-=inc;

        if(pressedD)
            i+=inc;

        if(inc<2 && !slowdown && (pressedA || pressedD))
            inc+= 0.01;

        if(slowdown && inc>=0.02) {
            inc-=0.2;
            if(inc <= 0.02){
                slowdown = false;
                pressedA = false;
                pressedD = false;
            }
            if(pressedA)
                i-=inc;

            if(pressedD)
                i+=inc;
        }

        //i = Math.round10(i, -2);
        System.out.println(inc);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setPaint(new Color(150, 150, 150));
        g2d.fillRect(20, 20, 80, 50);
        g2d.translate(180, -50);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(i), xPos+width/2, yPos+height/2);


        g2d.fillRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);

        g2d.dispose();

        //System.out.println("repainted");
    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("W is pressed");
            speed = 2;
            //slowdown = false;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            System.out.println("S is pressed");
            speed = -2;
            //slowdown = false;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            System.out.println("A is pressed");
            slowdown = false;


            pressedA = true;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            System.out.println("D is pressed");


            slowdown = false;
            pressedD = true;
        }
        this.i=i;
        }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
     }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        speed = 0;
        slowdown = true;

    }
```

*-edit-* so I think it might have something to do with the fact of where the rotation is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The angle value for the sin and cos function must be in radians. 
do something like this:

```
xPos += speed * Math.cos(-1*Math.PI*i/180);
```

this probably will solve your problem

Comment: no that didn't work, it is still having problems. It is still having trouble going the right direction, especially backwards.

Comment: maybe u can further explain what the problem is?

Comment: i know this is a trivial question, the inputs for both xpos and ypos are in radians right?

Comment: they should be unless im doing something wrong, im converting degrees to radians

Comment: So I did some testing and it breaks its movement between angles 60º-90º, 240º-300º when moving only on the x axis and between angles 0º-30º, 150º-180º when moving only on the y axis, in both the x and y axis respectively, the trig value is 0

Comment: i am at a loss here, u mean the output of what u have posted here gives xpos and y pos are in those ranges? by the way u are starting with value something like  i=-90 degrees?

Comment: no, i=0 at the start. What i meant is that whenever the object(rectangle) is within one of those angle ranges, it does not move along its respective axis.

Comment: i dont think the problem is with the math, i think it's with the way you use the listeners, i am not sure if using a infinite loop to keep updating your screen is a good way to do things, maybe you can check what is said here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997130/how-to-use-keylistener-with-jframe]. Maybe some else could help you out in this part, I think the best way to go about will be updating on a key event rather than through a loop